# bridge-routing and martian packets

Tags: routing, bridge, lxc

i am experimenting with routing a bit, and now i have a problem i cannot solve by myself

```
                              eth0 
                                |
                                |
                                |
    ------------------------   br0   ------------------------ 
    |                    (192.168.100.1)                    |
    |                                                       |
    |                                                       |
    |                                                       |
lxc_vpn_eth0                                          lxc_test_eth0                                              
(192.168.100.120)                                     (192.168.100.130)
    |
    |
   tun0
```

i want to send some packets (udp) out of the lxc-container (test) to the other lxc container (vpn) and from there through openvpn running inside this container, this works so far, but somehow the response is marked by the kernel as martian and dropped from the bridge br0

i tested with tcpdump on all 3 "places" the packets pass by and this are the results :
(in vpn container )
 `#tcpdump -i eth0`
    `21:25:12.043321 IP 192.168.100.1.55081 > XX.YY.UU.VV.6969: UDP, length 16`
    `21:25:12.097040 IP XX.YY.UU.VV.6969 > 192.168.100.1.55081: UDP, length 16`

as you see, i am masquerading the packets on tun0

so the packets from the test-container arive at the vpn container, go out through tun0 and i get an answer, but as soon as this response-packet is placed on the bridge i get this in kernel logs :
`kernel: [c0] IPv4: martian source 192.168.100.120 from XX.YY.UU.VV, on dev br0`

so how i have to configure the routing ,that the response packet doesn't get dropped? It should already be on the bridge where the container with ip 192.168.100.120 sits, and waits for it ...

Thx in advance for helping me out, i'll happily provide you with further informations ... ( i dont wanted to post all the routing tables, because i dont wanted to fill the posting with maybe useless informations )

Answer (score 0):

sry for that question ...

after hours of traffic sniffing, paket tracking and a lot of trail&error
i saw that i was masquerading the packets on br0 ...
i probably did this, cause with the containers, there are 2 computers on a hardware-switch wich needed routing on eth0. Anywany, that caused the strange src headers in the pakets ...

by masqerading the traffic on *eth0* rather then *br0*, i was able to solve this problem